# How to update acl on folder without recursion in Python

Tags: python, azure-data-lake

DataLakeDirectoryClient has update_access_control_recursive method which sets permissions on all child folders and files in Azure Datalake using Python. But IF I want to update ACl on specific folder without replacing all existing permissions (similar to update_access_control_recursive),  Is there a way?
I see one option is to get existing acl on folder and then append needed acl and use set_access_control to replace existing permissions. Is there a more efficient way?

DataLakeDirectoryClient.update_access_control_recursive(acl = acl)
DataLakeDirectoryClient.set_access_control